# How can I connect to DigitalOcean's MongoDB (v5.0) Dtabase with Trusted Sources set?

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

I createad a DigitalOcean's MongoDB (v5.0) Database and was able to connect to it from my machine, both from **Mongo Compass** and **Mongo CLI** .
But as soons as I add my machine IP (using DigitalOcean's automatic detect ip tool) as **Trusted Sources** on my MongoDB database console in DigitalOcean, I stop beign able to connect to it through my machine.

On **Mongo Compass** I got the error:
`Server selection timed out after 30000 ms`

On **Mongo CLI** I got the error:
`MongoDB shell version v5.0.2 connecting to: mongodb://<HOST>:27017/admin?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=<REPLICA>&ssl=true&tls=true {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-11T01:41:23.185Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":*******, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM host selection timeout","attr":{"replicaSet":"<REPLICA>","error":"FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"nearest\" } for set <REPLICA>"}} Error: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "nearest" } for set <REPLICA>, <REPLICA>/<HOST>:27017 : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17 @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1`

I already tried to paste my ipv6 that I got from the command line `curl ifconfig.io` as Trusted Source of my database in DigitalOcean's console, but even after that I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You provided only one host `<HOST>:27017`. You should provide all host of the replica set, e.g. `<HOST-1>:27017,<HOST-2>:27017,<HOST-3>:27017`.

Comment: Why do you specify `ssl=true&tls=true`, usually it would be only one of them. And you may miss the `tlsCAFile`. Perhpaps Mongo CLI uses the system stored CA if not provided.

Comment: I tried to connect using the ***Conection String*** that DigitalOcean provides.


`mongo "mongodb+srv://doadmin:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>/admin?replicaSet=<REPLICA>&tls=true&authSource=admin" --tls`

I haven't find any other replica set host on DigitalOcean console. Also, I wasn't able to find the ca-certificate that DigitalOcean provided in the past.

Comment: Option `--tlsUseSystemCA` may work if you don't have the CA-certificate - if it is stored in your system.

Comment: Even using `--tlsUseSystemCA` option it didn't work.

Comment: Can you connect without TLS? Did you try the new `mongosh`?

Comment: For future references, it seems there's a bug in DigitalOcean automatic detect ip tool. It's detecting the wrong ip address of my machine.
As soon as I got my right ipv4 (https://whatismyipaddress.com/) and inserted on DigitalOcean's Trusted Sources , I was able to connect to my database.